# Order Import Magento 1.4.x

Tags: magento

How to move orders on magento 1.4.x using imp/exp profiles ?

Comment: are both Magento installations the exact same version?

Answer (score 1):

Magento has no built in way of doing an order import export with imp/exp profiles.  If you want orders from an different system imported into a different system, it means

1. Programmatically exporting the orders, customers, shipments, invoices, etc. from one system
2. Programmatically importing the orders into the new system

It's not a trivial task. If you're not up for a long learning process you'll need a developer or firm that's done it before to do it for you.

Comment: I alredy know how action parse and adapter works, but I wan't know if somebody has done something similar.

Comment: I haven't seen any module or description of how to do it.  I suspect it's pretty difficult.

Answer (score 0):

If both installations are the exact same version of Magento, you could try taking a mysqldump for all tables that start with `sales_` and insert those records into your target system.  The trick would be to make sure that the ID values match up across all the key relationships.

You'll need to make sure that the corresponding customers and their addresses already exist in the new system too, probably, as I imagine there would be foreign keys into those tables too.

Make sure you take lots of backups before you try that.

Good luck and please report back how it goes!

Cheers,
Jonathan

Comment: I don't think that its necessary to get old customers matching on sales ids with customer_id: when you delete a customer or a product on magento sales will not deleted...

Comment: you should be able to check the foreign key constraints in the `information_schema` database in your mysql server.  Did it work doing the SQL insert?